# How to get different parent class for different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a content page with some text in it that is full width inside the container. However I want the image in the article to be full width (not inside the container but on the whole screen, so 100% width), and for that the container class needs to be 'container-fluid'. But only for the image and not for the entire article.

Is this possible?

Have the text listen to: 'container' and the image to 'container-fluid'? I'm using bootstrap so the structure needs to stay the same, I can't just add a div around the image tag with class name 'container-fluid'.

Part of my code (posting everything is not needed)

```
<div class="container relative">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="col-sm-12 ">
            <!-- Post -->
            <div class="blog-item mb-20 mb-xs-40">
                <!-- Text -->
                <div class="blog-item-body">
                    <!-- <h1 class="mt-0 font-alt"><?echo $contenti[0]['title']?></h1> -->
                    <? 
                        echo ContentCPS($contenti[0]['description']);

                        $content    = "SELECT * FROM `lb_categories` WHERE alias = '".$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['alias'])."' and id NOT IN ('43') ";
                        $contentcon = $conn->query($content);
                        while ($content = $contentcon->fetch_array()){

                            $article_images = $content['params']; // Get image parameters of the article
                            $pictures = json_decode($article_images); // Split the parameters apart

                            $afbeelding .= '<img src="cms/'.$pictures->{'image'}.'">';
                        }
                        echo $afbeelding;

                        echo $contenti[0]['introtext'];

                    ?>      
                </div>
                <!-- End Text -->

            </div>
```

So the image needs to listen to 'container-fluid relative', and the rest to 'container relative', if that is possible.

Comment: please post some of your code

Comment: I added part of it, although it's not really needed I think @messerbill

Answer (score 0):

You can get the immediate parent for specific element:

```
$(this).closest("div.container");
```

Comment: But can I make two elements listen to a different class for the same parent?

Comment: $(this).closest("div.container, div.container2"); // get the first parent element with some those classes

Comment: Thank you but it is 1 year later I probably solved it already :P